# jquery removeClass for all but the first item?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm doing the following right now which works great:

```
 $('#picker a').removeClass('selected');
```

where:

```
<div id="picker">
 <a href="" class="selected">Stuff</a>
 <a href="" class="selected">Stuff</a>
 <a href="" class="">Stuff</a>
 <a href="" class="selected">Stuff</a>
</div>
```

How can I update the jQuery to say, remove class selected from all BUT the first row. Ignore the first row in picker.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

```
$('#picker > a').slice(1).removeClass('selected');
```

This uses a valid `querySelectorAll` selector, along with the [`slice()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method which will be very fast.

Comment: @alex: Thanks. I get bored, but I think I'll be content with SRV for a little longer. ;o)

Answer (score 3):

Negate [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector), like this:

```
$('#picker a:not(:first)').removeClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
$('#picker a').not(':first-child').removeClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 1):

For an alternative :)

```
$('#picker a:gt(0)').removeClass('selected');
```